# Filter certain text out of string

Tags: java, android, regex, string, filter

For a project I set myself I have to filter a 10 character string out of a URL.

For example:

> https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/SOMETEXTHERE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I want to  filter out the **SOMETEXTHERE**.
But this characters are changing so I can't just say that it is always the same.

Are there any existing functions or so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex for this task:

```
final String string = "https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B001VGASYA/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1";
final String replacement = String.format("$1%s$3", "REPLACED");
final String result = string.replaceFirst("(.*product\\/)([^\\/]+)(.*)", replacement); // or .replaceAll()
System.out.println(result);
```

**Breakdown:**

`(.*product\\/)([^\\/]+)(.*)`

- 1st Capturing Group `(.*product\\/)`

  - `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) product matches the characters product literally (case sensitive)
  - `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
- 2nd Capturing Group `([^\\/]+)`

  - Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\/]+`
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
- 3rd Capturing Group `(.*)`

  - `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Answer (score 2):

If are you sure that only the text that you mentioned will change you can split the string by "/" character then just take the right string from list.

```
String URL = "https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B001VGASYA/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1";
    String targetString = Arrays.asList(URL.split("/")).get(5);
```